# How to find distinct years from a table with multiple years in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a table with several hundred records, each one containing a datetime column. What is the most efficient way to find the distinct years from that datetime field?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using Ruby (this would require loading all the records, though):

```
Model.select("my_datetime").map{ |item| item.my_datetime.year }.uniq
```

Using SQL (this example is for PostgreSQL, I can update it with your specific database):

```
# PostgreSQL
Model.select("distinct(extract(year from my_datetime))")

# MySQL
Model.select("distinct(year(my_datetime))")

# SQLite
Model.select("strftime('%Y', my_datetime)")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(YEAR(created_at)) FROM your_table
```

will probably work, but is heavily dependent of your used database (This will of course work with MySQL).

`ActiveRecord` is a pain in the ass if you want using custom SQL statements, using Ruby statements like

```
Model.all.map(&:created_at).map(&:year).uniq
```

is indeed beautifuler, though it can be really slow because of loading and iterating over all your records.

Answer (score 2):

This will return an array of years directly from the database in PostgreSQL:

```
YourModel.pluck("DISTINCT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM my_datetime)::Integer")
```

Answer (score 1):

This will return the unique years in an array:

`years = Model.pluck(:created_at).map{|x| x.year}.uniq`